# Combine GroupBy with sort/dictsort

Tags: nunjucks, obsidian

I'm trying to get some of my templates in Obsidian working together with using Zotero and for this I want to write a corresponding (adapted) template.

I'm almost happy with it but still struggling with one thing:
Annotations from Zotero are properly read by the Obsidian plugin which extracts them based on their highlighting color and even grouping works as I would like to. However, I would like to have a certain order in which they're imported.

The following is a macro I'm using for a different function and it shows the Order I would like to have the groups sorted:

```
{%- macro colorValueToName(color) -%}
    {%- switch color -%}
        {%- case "#ff6666" -%}
            Questionable
        {%- case "#2ea8e5" -%}
            TODO / follow up
        {%- case "#ffd400" -%}
            Important
        {%- case "#a28ae5" -%}
            Interesting
        {%- case "#5fb236" -%}
            Good
        {%- default -%}
            Interesting but not relevant
    {%- endswitch -%}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

Now, when  "Good"  (green) comes before "Questionable" in the annotations, the order will be accordingly. I understand, that I'll have to define most likely a dict and use dictsort somehow but I'm unsure how to do so.

The relevant code part where the annotations are fetched and group is this:

```
## Annotations
{% persist "annotations" %}
{% set annots = annotations | filterby("date", "dateafter", lastImportDate) -%}
{% if annots.length > 0 %}
### Imported on {{importDate | format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a")}}

{% for color, annots in annots | groupby("color") -%}
#### {{colorValueToName(color)}}

{% for annot in annots -%}
> [!quote{% if annot.color %}|{{annot.color}}{% endif %}] {{calloutHeader(annot.type)}}

[...removed unrelated code]

{% endfor -%}
{% endfor -%}
{% endif %}
{% endpersist %}
```

I'm open for thoughts and suggestions. I would think that somewhat has to be done with **{% for color, annots in annots | groupby("color") -%}**

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem and found the problem is hard to solve by combining "groupby" and "sort". So I use a workaround solution that predefines an ordered list of colors and then uses "filterby" to select the entries with the specific color. Please take a look at the code snippet below.

```
{%- set colorToColorCategorie = {
"#5fb236": "green",
"#ffd400": "yellow",
"#ff6666": "red",
"#2ea8e5": "blue",
"#a28ae5": "purple",
"#e56eee": "magenta",
"#f19837": "orange"
}
-%}

{% for color, colorCategorie in colorToColorCategorie %}
{%- for annotation in annotations | filterby ("color", "startswith", color) -%}
do something
{% endfor -%}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you. And you can see the entire template I'm using on my github: https://github.com/nano8259/obsidian-literature-note. It is incomplete for lacking support of notes. I will completeit when I have time.

Have a nice day : )